# Mat Icon not displaying svgIcon using addSvgIconSetInNamespace through MatIconRegistry

Tags: angular, mat-icon

I have a single file with multiple svg inside, I register that file using `MatIconRegistry` in a IconsModule.ts file

```
@NgModule()
export class IconsModule {
  constructor(
    private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private _matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry
  ) {
    _matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSetInNamespace(
      'feather',
      _domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'assets/icons/feather-icons.svg'
      )
    );
}
}
```

Now in app.module.ts i import the Icons Module and use the icon in a
html component

```
<mat-icon class="text-black" svgIcon="feather:menu"></mat-icon>
```

Something happens when instead of registering the entire icon set, I register just one icon in a separate file using `addSvgIcon` and it works.

But I would like to register all the svg in `addSvgIconSetInNamespace()`

The entire svg file that i have is

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="arrow-left" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="user-check" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-user-check"><path d="M16 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="8.5" cy="7" r="4"></circle><polyline points="17 11 19 13 23 9"></polyline></svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sun" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-sun"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="5"></circle><line x1="12" y1="1" x2="12" y2="3"></line><line x1="12" y1="21" x2="12" y2="23"></line><line x1="4.22" y1="4.22" x2="5.64" y2="5.64"></line><line x1="18.36" y1="18.36" x2="19.78" y2="19.78"></line><line x1="1" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"></line><line x1="21" y1="12" x2="23" y2="12"></line><line x1="4.22" y1="19.78" x2="5.64" y2="18.36"></line><line x1="18.36" y1="5.64" x2="19.78" y2="4.22"></line></svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sunrise" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-sunrise"><path d="M17 18a5 5 0 0 0-10 0"></path><line x1="12" y1="2" x2="12" y2="9"></line><line x1="4.22" y1="10.22" x2="5.64" y2="11.64"></line><line x1="1" y1="18" x2="3" y2="18"></line><line x1="21" y1="18" x2="23" y2="18"></line><line x1="18.36" y1="11.64" x2="19.78" y2="10.22"></line><line x1="23" y1="22" x2="1" y2="22"></line><polyline points="8 6 12 2 16 6"></polyline></svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="moon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-moon"><path d="M21 12.79A9 9 0 1 1 11.21 3 7 7 0 0 0 21 12.79z"></path></svg>
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="menu" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-menu"><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line></symbol>
</svg>
```